# when $ \ v(t)=0 \ $?

Tags: calculus

Let $ \ a(t) , \  v(t) \ \ and \ \ s(t) \ $ denote the acceleration , velocity and position of a particle at time $ \ t \ $. Given $ \ a(t)=3 \cos (t)-2 \sin (t) , \ \ s(0)=0 , \ v(0)=4 \ $.  Then find

(i) when $ \ v(t)=0 \ $ ?

(ii) when $ \ v(t) \ $ will be maximum in positive direction ?

(iii) when $ \ v(t) \ $ will be maximum in Negative direction ?

**Answer:**

(i)

$ a(t)=3 \cos t-2 \sin t \\ \Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t} =3 \cos t-2 \sin t \ $

Integrating ,we get

$ v(t)= 3 \sin t+2 \cos t+c \ $  , where $ \ c \ $ is arbitrary constant.

Using $ \ v(0)=4 \ $ , we get

$ c=2 \ $

Thus,

$ v(t)=3 \sin t+2 \cos t+2 \ $

Now $ \ v(t)=0 \\ \Rightarrow 3 \sin t+2 \cos t+2 =0 \ $

But I can not solve for $ \ t \ $.

Is my process is correct?

Comment: Hint: At what time t is sin t = 0 and cos t = -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint $$a\cos x+b\sin x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin x \right) \\ =\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\phi) \\ \phi =\tan^{-1}(a/b)$$

$v(t)$ is maximum in positive or negative direction when it's derivative i.e the acceleration is $0$. So you find the solutions of $$3\cos t-2\sin t=0 \\ \tan t =3/2 \\ t=\tan^{-1}(3/2), \pi+\tan^{-1}(3/2)$$ 
Substitute these values in velocity.

Comment: what about the next parts? I mean when the velocity $ \ v(t) \ $ will be maximum in positive direction ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following substitution :
**y=tan (t/2)**

This would give you **sin t=2y/(1+y^2)** and **cos t=(1-y^2)/(1+y^2)**

Applying this to your equation **2cos t+3sin t+2=0**,you get **4+6y=0**

This can be solved for y and in turn t.

You get t as **x = 2 (π n - tan^(-1)(2/3))** where n is an integer. Take only positive values of t since it represents the time in your case.

The second and third parts of the question can be figured out using the second derivative tests.For part (ii) you need a maxima and for (iii) you need a minima.In case,you are not sure of how this works,you can check it here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is another hint:

If we write S=sin(t), then your equation can be written as:
$$3S+2\sqrt{1-S^2}-2=0$$
This can be readily manipulated to give:
$$13S^2-12S=0$$
From this we deduce that sin(t) can be either 0 (an invalid answer) or 12/13.   The second answer is correct and so we also deduce that we will have solutions at arcsin(12/13) = 62.38... deg or 112.62... deg.  Again, only the latter is valid.

However, this method is clumsy and indirect.  I prefer the following as more direct and easier to follow.  Any expression involving a sum like this can be rewritten:
$$Asin(t)+Bcos(t)=Csin(t+\phi)$$
By using the simple compound angle formula for sin(A+B) we can readily deduce that $$C=\sqrt{(A^2+B^2)}$$ and $$tan(\phi)=B/A$$
Therefore, your equation can be written as $$\sqrt{13}.sin(t+\phi)+2=0$$ which is easy to solve for t.

As for the other parts of your question, finding maxima and minima involves setting the first derivative to zero and solving.